# JQuery Autocomplete - multiple results

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm having a problem getting the autocomplete to work.

My autocomplete box is showing multiple results, not related to a DISTINCT problem.

Example: if my autocomplete is showing 2 possible options then it shows the results twice in the autocomplete box - i.e. Lungs, Liver then Lungs, Liver again. If there were three possible autocomplete options then the result list is repeated three times and so on.

In Firebug I can see the correct Json is being returned, results are not duplicated.

Here's a [screen grab:](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33793648/screen4.jpg)

Does anyone know what the problem is, please?

Regards
Melt

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetSR',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { term: request.term },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {

                response($.map(json, function (label, value) {
                    return json;

                }));

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error - ' + textStatus);
               // console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {

       //  alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.label + ' ID: ' + ui.item.value);
          $('#search').val(ui.item.label);

        // save the auto complete value id to be used later
        setACValue(ui.item.value); 

        return false;
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function (json) {
                response($.map(json, function (label, value) {
                    return json;
                }));
            },
```

should be:

```
success: function (json) {
                response($.map(json, function (label, value) {
                    return value;
                }));
            },
```

You're returning the whole JSON array each time you process an element of the JSON element array, instead of just returning that one element's value. So your `$.map` is returning a two-dimensional array.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
success: function (json) {
                response(json);
            },
```